# App Crashes with: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: objective-c

The "Back" button in my app, when pressed, correctly takes me to the main view/screen, then the app crashes, Debug screen giving me this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RLMRealmNotificationToken invalidate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003bd57e0

I stepped through the code with Debug and see the last line of code executed before it crashes.

In the code I see this error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" and have read here that this is likely related to the IBAction not working properly on my Back button but can't figure out where the issue is in the code.  My project does not show the Back button on the Storyboard, as it is coded.

Here is the code where my CustomBackButton is defined.

```
#import "ViewControllerHelper.h"
#import "ProfileRealm.h"

@interface ViewControllerHelper ()

- (void)setCustomTitle;
- (void)setCustomBackButton;
- (void)profilesAction:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewControllerHelper

- (id)initWithViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController       andProfile:(ProfileRealm *)profile {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _viewController = viewController;
        _profile = profile;

        [self setCustomTitle];
        [self setCustomBackButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setCustomTitle {
    if (_profile == nil)
        return;

    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString     alloc] initWithString:_profile.name];

    UIFont *font1 = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font1 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

    [string appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"]];

    NSUInteger start = string.length;

    [string appendAttributedString:[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_profile.friendlyName]];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(start, string.length - start)];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrapStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragrapStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [string addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrapStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,44,44)];
    [titleLabel setAttributedText:string];
    [titleLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    //    [titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    _viewController.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
}

- (void)setCustomBackButton {
    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:  [UIImage imageNamed:@"monkeys"]
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                            target:self     action:@selector(profilesAction:)];
    _viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
}

- (void)profilesAction:(id)sender {
    //MARK - App Crashes after next line is executed
    [_viewController.tabBarController.navigationController  popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end


    //Post Crash, I get a SIGABRT error in the main file
    // Here is that code:

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,      NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this could be due to the "invalidate" method not being a recognized selector. Try using `[RLMRealmNotificationToken stop];` instead per their [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/2.2.0/api/Classes/RLMNotificationToken.html)

Comment: Thanks!  I inherited this project. Parts of the code had [RLMRealmNotificationToken stop];  but those lines threw an error to "use -invalidate instead"  . But I will read up on their documentation. Thanks again.

Comment: Is the selector it's looking for `invalidate` and `-invalidate`?

Comment: "invalidate" only, I believe. Apologies for the "-"

Comment: Did they throw an error, or did the compiler complain?

Comment: It was one of the red highlighted alerts to the right of the line of code, with an exclamation point.  Said -stop should be updated to be invalidate, instead.

Comment: Did you verify the the RLMRealmNotificationToken is still in memory, and that it was not yet deallocated?

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler complains that you should use "invalidate" instead of "stop", and at runtime "invalidate" is not recognised, then I would suspect that you are using an old compiled library together with new incompatible header files.

Say version 1.0 of your library used "stop". You received 2.0 header files where the method changed to "invalidate" but you continue using the compiled 1.0 library.

But usually this is caused by a reference to an object being declared as one thing, while the actual object is another thing.

Comment: Thank you!  This makes sense. I will dig into it and let ou know what I find.  Thank you again for your wisdom and help!

Comment: Here is an example of where I get the stop vs invalidate error: 
-(void)dealloc {
  [self.token stop];     //Error on this line is ->.  'stop' is unavailable: Renamed to -invalidate.
    self.token = nil;
}